# TextToSpeech queue has poor performance when two languages are used simultaneously

Tags: android, performance, text-to-speech

I need to use TTS on Android to speak two languages simultaneously: one phrase in EN and another in DE. For this purposes I provided two different implementations of TextToSpeech.OnInitListener. Everything works so far. Then I'm trying to speak them, the auxiliary function:

```
// wait for speaker availability
public boolean isSpeakingWait(tts) {

    int N = 50;
    int i = 0;
    while( tts.isSpeaking() && i < N ) {
        i--;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return i == 50;
}
```

and call for speak:

```
isSpeakWait(ttsEN);
ttsEN.speak(strEN, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
isSpeakWait(ttsDE);
ttsDE.speak(strDE, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

and it look like after pushing into Queue I might wait for several seconds before sound, and it 's happend for both en and de calls.

Sometimes I can see the following error just between EN and DE phrases:

```
W/TextToSpeech﹕ isSpeaking failed: not bound to TTS engine
W/TextToSpeech﹕ speak failed: not bound to TTS engine
```

I suppose, the issue is with changing language of TTS (because EN I emit to TTS initialized with en-us, while DE is emitted to TTS initialized with de-de). Any suggestions on performance improving ?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that silence time after pushing german word and generated voice is around 8 seconds, when for english word is about 2 seconds

Answer (score 1):

too late to answer but yes, TTS is like a singleton.5- 8 seconds is laтguage loading. So 2 instances of tts is the same if 1 instance with tts.setLanguage() before every speaking.